# Why does wifi hotspot doesn't work correctly?

Tags: wireless, networking, hot-spot

I have created the wifi hotspot. In windows, it used to display wifi signal on my nokia C3 but after creating wifi hotspot from ubuntu, I am facing certain problem.

Nokia C3 doesn't even gets wifi signal.

But wifi signal appears in my samsung mobile GTS3-850 and I can access wifi if I put wifi security option to "none"

On the other hand, if I create password then 
Nomatters, if I type right password or not, it doesn't connect to that wifi.

Note : I use Wimax to access internet.

Comment: You don't see the network? I know this has been an issue on some devices. You should find an option to connect to a hidden network. That worked on my N8, in any case.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Can't we make that network visible? There's no such option like connect to hidden network in C3.

Comment: I don't know why the network isn't always visible. Some devices seem to see it and other don't. I don't know that this is what's going on in your case though. But it's something to test if you have access to another phone.

Comment: Ya, Jo, as you said network is visible in my other phone but not visible in this nokia c3. In windows, case was different, I was able to use hotspot. I just want to know is it ubuntu issue or not.

Comment: You can connect to a hidden network on Nokia C3, you just have to add the network manually, `WLAN` > `Saved WLANS` > `Options` > `Add new network` > `Add manually`

Comment: @ArK Thanks but that also didn't work in my case. 
:(

Comment: This is interesting. I just had an opportunity to test this again, this time on 13.10. My Nokia N8 still finds the network and connects without any issues, but my Android-devices doesn't find them and doesn't connect even when I enter the ssid.

Comment: I connected my Nexus 5 mobile to the wifi using hotspot on desktop. Apps like Whatsapp and facebook are working but other apps are not working. Even I cant download apps..Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer for you now.

I had an opportunity to test this with an Android device and it just doesn't work. The reason is that Android no longer supports ad-hoc networks, meaning that I'd have to configure my hotspot using the "Infrastructure" setting in the dialog like you can see in the screenshot below. Unfortunately, my Wifi adapter doesn't support that.

If your Wifi adapter supports it, I think that should work with both Android and your Nokia C3, but since I have no way of actually testing it, I'd appreciate if you could and provide feedback. :)

[image]

Comment: Seems like even my wifi adaptor doesn't support that feature. Anyway, thanks. :)

Comment: There are probably other solutions though, so don't give up. :)

Comment: No, I won't give up. That's what I'm learning. :)